# Why is my code seg faulting when trying to add a filter to the bmp file that was inputed?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bmp

I am trying to add a given filter onto a bmp file but it is segfaulting at the first addition of the filter array and tempRed (I found this using gdb). I thought it was because it was trying the access memory from the array[-1] but since we start at 1 I don't think that would be the case. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
int edgeDect(struct HEADER *Header, struct INFOHEADER *InfoHeader, struct PIXEL **Data){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char filter[3][3] =
    {{0, -1, 0},
     {-1, 4, -1},
     {0, -1, 0}};
    char tempRed, tempGreen, tempBlue;

    for(i = 1; i < InfoHeader->Height - 1; i++){
            for(j = 1; j < InfoHeader->Width - 1; j++){
                    printf("The height is %d\n",i);
                    printf("The width is %d\n", j);

                    tempRed = 0;
                    tempGreen = 0;
                    tempBlue = 0;
                    //***Where seg fault occurs
                    tempRed += (filter[0][0] * Data[i-1][j-1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[0][0] * Data[i-1][j-1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[0][0] * Data[i-1][j-1].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[0][1] * Data[i-1][j].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[0][1] * Data[i-1][j].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[0][1] * Data[i-1][j].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[0][2] * Data[i-1][j+1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[0][2] * Data[i-1][j+1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[0][2] * Data[i-1][j+1].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[1][0] * Data[i][j-1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[1][0] * Data[i][j-1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[1][0] * Data[i][j-1].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[1][1] * Data[i][j].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[1][1] * Data[i][j].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[1][1] * Data[i][j].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[1][2] * Data[i][j+1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[1][2] * Data[i][j+1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[1][2] * Data[i][j+1].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[2][0] * Data[i+1][j-1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[2][0] * Data[i+1][j-1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[2][0] * Data [i+1][j-1].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[2][1] * Data[i+1][j].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[2][1] * Data[i+1][j].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[2][1] * Data[i+1][j].Blue);

                    tempRed += (filter[2][2] * Data[i+1][j+1].Red);
                    tempGreen += (filter[2][2] * Data[i+1][j+1].Green);
                    tempBlue += (filter[2][2] * Data[i+1][j+1].Blue);

                    Data[i][j].Red = tempRed;
                    Data[i][j].Green = tempGreen;
                    Data[i][j].Blue = tempBlue;
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct PIXEL *ColorData;
    struct INFOHEADER InfoHeader;
    unsigned char red, green, blue;
    struct HEADER Header;

    //Checks to make sure that there are enough command line arguments
    if(argc != 6){
            printf("Not enough input arguments in the command line.\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("Inputing the information into the header structs.\n");
    //Inputs the header information into the header structs
    InputHeaders(argv[1], &InfoHeader, &Header);

    printf("Inputing the RGB componets into the struct.\n");
    //Inputs the colors from the picture into is RGB comnponets
    inputColors(argv[1], &InfoHeader, &ColorData, &Header);

    //Gets the integer value for the colors from the command line
    red = atoi(argv[3]);
    green = atoi(argv[4]);
    blue = atoi(argv[5]);

    printf("Adding filter to input image\n");
    //Edge detctor: FInd the edge of the picture
    edgeDect(&Header, &InfoHeader, &ColorData);
    printf("Saving the filter into outputfilename(edge).bmp.\n");
    //Saves the edge data to the correct output file
    saveEdge(argv[2], &InfoHeader, &Header, &ColorData);

    printf("Color changing function adding the command line numbers to the current RGB values.\n");
    //Changes the color of each RGB pixel with the inputed command line values
    colorChange(&ColorData, red, green, blue, &InfoHeader);
    printf("Saving the new bmp file with the color change\n");
    //Saves te shade file to the correct output file
    saveShade(argv[2], &InfoHeader, &Header, &ColorData);


return 0;
}
```

Storing the RGB values:

```
int inputColors(char *filename, struct INFOHEADER *InfoHeader, struct PIXEL **Data, struct HEADER *Header){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    FILE *inputFile;

    //Opens up the file so that it can be read from
    if((inputFile = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL){
            printf("Unable to open .bmp file\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    //Mallocing enough space for the 2D structures of pixels (colors)
    Data = (struct PIXEL **)malloc(InfoHeader->Height * sizeof(struct PIXEL *));
    for(i = 0; i < InfoHeader->Height; i++){
            Data[i] = (struct PIXEL *)malloc(InfoHeader->Width * sizeof(struct PIXEL));
    }

    //This goes until after we are down with the header
    fseek(inputFile, Header->Offset, SEEK_SET);

    //Inputing the data into the malloced struct
    i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < InfoHeader->Height; ++i){
            for(j = 0; j < InfoHeader->Width; ++j){
            //      printf("Width is %d\n", i);
            //      printf("Height is %d\n", j);
                    Data[i][j].Red = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The Red componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Red);
                    Data[i][j].Green = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The green componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Green);
                    Data[i][j].Blue = getc(inputFile);
            //      printf("The blue componet is %X\n", Data[i][j].Blue);
            }
    }

    fclose(inputFile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that Data array dimensions are [InfoHeader->Height][InfoHeader->Width]? Also, you are passing the pointer Header, but never using it.

Comment: In which case what you are passing to `struct PIXEL **Data` is wrong. Nothing else on that line is suspect.

Comment: I am storing the RGB values of each pixel in struct PIXEL **Data

Comment: We can see that, but the code posted does not show how the argument for `**Data` is defined and how it is passed to `edgeDect()`. BTW I think `char tempRed, tempGreen, tempBlue;` should be `int` because a pixel value `* 4` can break the `char` value before the subtractions are made.

Comment: @WeatherVane I just added my main and the function that inputs the RGB values into Data

Comment: In function `inputColors` there is a flaw in the memory allocation because `Data = (struct PIXEL **)malloc(InfoHeader->Height * sizeof(struct PIXEL *));` does not set the variable `struct PIXEL *ColorData;` in `main` whose address was passed. There needs to be a `*` such as `*Data = malloc(InfoHeader->Height * sizeof(struct PIXEL *));` but I can't go further as I can't compile and run a complete program.

Answer (score 0):

The line in `inputColors` where you assign to `Data` will set the value of `Data` within that function.  Its value will not be passed back to the caller (`main`), leaving `ColorData` uninitialized when you try to use it later.

To pass the 2D array you create in `inputColors`, you need to pass data as `struct PIXEL ***Data`, assign it with `*Data = malloc`, and change `ColorData` in `main` to be `struct PIXEL **ColorData`.  It can simplify your use of the newly allocated memory in `inputColors` by assigning that memory to a local variable (call it `Data`, and change the parameter to `struct PIXEL ***pData`), and only using the parameter name the one time when you store it (`*pData = Data;`).

Alternatively, don't pass `Data` as a parameter at all.  Pass it back to the caller in a `return` statement.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. If I want to pass it back, can I leave it as it is now as just a double pointer?

Comment: Yes, but you still need to change the declaration of `ColorData` in `main` (with appropriate changes to its use).

Comment: Cool. Thanks so much!

Comment: So if I am passing back the pointer to main, how would you pass the information into another function if the data is needed in another function. Would I pass it in the same way I did in inputColors?

Comment: @sarah `edgeDect` wouldn't change, and you'd pass the variable's value `ColorData` instead of the address (`&ColorData`).